# Word for terror at the idea of being infinitely born again into different bodies

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes terror at the idea of being infinitely born back into the world, trapped in a cycle that never ends and is inescapable.

Possibly a word that relates to religion or philosophy.

Comment: You might wanna ask the guys at Buddhism SE or Hinduism SE about this. If such a word exists, it's almost certainly of religious origin.

Comment: @HotLicks If you feel OP's question is not useful, you can explain it to them in a serious way. Sarcasm is probably not the best idea towards new users whom we should welcome to the site.

Comment: @Fiksdal It's ok. He has a right to express himself and how he feels.

Comment: *Samsar**a**phobia* does have a nice ring!

Comment: Actually, even the Buddhists/Hindus probably wouldn't have a word for this exact thing, due to the criterion of "inescapable". In those religions, said cycle is in fact said to be escapable. (I.E. when attaining Enlightenment/Liberation.) So you're looking for a word to describe the mental state of a follower of a Dharmic religion who is suffering from phobia due to a misunderstanding of the teachings of his religion. I feel for that guy.

Comment: @Fiksdal - Actually, I think it's a fairly good example of how one might apply simile to the problem.

Comment: Can we make multiple word requests? I guess every word is at least partially another word, but is it possible to ask for two words at once, or is that now allowed here?

Comment: @HotLicks What situation? And what was? And yeah, no huge snark. But in written communication it's difficult to express tone.

Comment: You can make a "phrase-request".

Comment: And hover over "single-word-request" above.  Note that you must provide an example of use.

Comment: @Fiksdal I have asked this question http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/8076/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-site to check what questions people would like asked and not asked on this site. I am wary about changing a question people like in case it upsets people here. At the moment it seems people like it. But they did not like the other question of mine being asked, so it seemed.

Comment: Although it doesn’t **require** [the notions or fear of] rebirth or endless **cycles**, [“Apeirophobia”](http://phobia.wikia.com/wiki/Apeirophobia) is apparently the fear of eternity or infinity, which would include the notions/fear of being somewhere, [trapped] inescapably forever.

Comment: A few years ago I was talking to a friend of mine; he was raised in a Buddhist family but isn't religious.  "My brother, though - he's like, a born-again Buddhist!"  My response: "Doesn't that mean he's doing it wrong?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no single word as far as I know. You might call it ***metaphysical dread/horror/panic*** to emphasize that the dread/horror/panic is rooted in a metaphysical possibility.

Nietzsche called the burden of experiencing your own life infinitely many times ***the greatest weight***:

> The *greatest weight*—What, if some day or night a demon were to steal
>   after you into your loneliest loneliness and say to you: "This life as
>   you now live it and have lived it, you will have to live once more and
>   innumerable times more; and there will be nothing new in it, but every
>   pain and every joy and every thought and sigh and everything
>   unutterably small or great in your life will have to return to you,
>   all in the same succession and sequence - even this spider and this
>   moonlight between the trees, and even this moment and I myself. The
>   eternal hourglass of existence is turned upside down again and again,
>   and you with it, speck of dust!" ([here](http://www.theperspectivesofnietzsche.com/nietzsche/nrecur.html))

The reason I mention this is because perhaps some of the literature on Nietzsche will contain a term describing the potential horror one feels at the idea of cyclic rebirth or the similar idea of eternal return.

Comment: Very interesting. I presume this would be "the greatest weight" only if one knew with certainty that it was happening? Or is the mere possibility of being a meaningless player in this endless scheme "the greatest weight?"

Comment: @medica, certainly the very possibility is terrifying. But Nietzsche actually thought that it was both true and provable. He even took a break from philosophy in order to study physics in an attempt to prove it! But for him, it was only "the greatest weight" if one was not embracing their life. Once one begins to embrace life and approves of every one of one's own actions, the fact of eternal recurrence actually becomes exhilarating. That's a lot of what's behind Nietzsche's idea of *amor fati*  (love of fate), IMO.

Comment: I love the diverse things I learn here. Thanks so much. *Amor fati.* I will read about that.

Answer (score 8):

As I suggested in a now deleted comment, you could use the word **Samsaraphobia**.

Please note that this is not an established word, by any means. (The adjective *Samsaraphobic* has been used a little bit online, but it's definitely not in any dictionary.)

> [Samsara](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/samsara): *(Dharmic religions)* The endless series of births, deaths, and rebirths to which all beings are subject.

> [Phobia](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/phobia): A persistent, irrational fear of a specific object, activity, or situation that leads to a compelling desire to avoid it.

Please note that even this word might not fully satisfy your criteria in OP.

This is due to your criterion:

> a cycle that never ends and is inescapable.

The word "Samsara" stems from the Sanskrit language and the religious texts of Dharmic religions. In those religions, *Samsara* is not at all seen as inescapable. On the contrary, the major teaching of those religions is that Samsara *is* in fact escapable. Not only that, doing so is in fact the *ultimate goal* of those religions. Hence, samsara can by no means be described as something *inescapable*.

However, *phobia* can mean an "irrational" fear. So that might make sense, then.